AVAudioEngine inside an AsyncStream does not work?
In this sampled version of my code, I try to wrap the AVAudioEngine and its audio buffer generation inside an AsyncStream.
The same code directly printing without the AsyncStream works, but this audioStream here stays awaiting at the for await in  line
@preconcurrency import AVFoundation
import SwiftUI

struct MinimalSampleView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello World")
            .task {
                print("start task")

                let audioStream = AsyncStream<Double> { continuation in
                    // Add AVAudioSession.. setCategory & setActive for simulators
                    let audioEngine = AVAudioEngine()
                    let format = audioEngine.inputNode.outputFormat(forBus: 0)
                    audioEngine.inputNode.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: 1024, format: format) {  (buffer: AVAudioPCMBuffer, when: AVAudioTime) in
                        print("never called")
                        continuation.yield(when.audioTimeStamp.mSampleTime)
                    }
                    do {
                        try audioEngine.start()
                        print("did start")
                    }
                    catch { continuation.finish() }
                }

                print("await for sampleTime")
                for await sampleTime in audioStream {
                    print("\(sampleTime) never called")
                }

                print("end task")
            }
    }
}

I was initially trying to wrap this code inside an Actor having the following interface
func start()
func stop()
func getStream() -> AsyncStream<UncheckedSendableAudioBufferWrapper>?

But in that case instead of nothing, I was met with an
“Incorrect actor executor assumption” on the for await audioBuffer in audioStream { line
And... I just found out that if I add a termination before the do { } the stream start without any runtime error.
continuation.onTermination = { termination in
    audioEngine.inputNode.removeTap(onBus: 0)
    audioEngine.stop()
}

I'm completely lost here, can someone explain/understand:

why adding the onTermination make the stream start?
why is it not starting in the first place
how to avoid the runtime error with the incorrect actor executor assumption?

Xcode: 16.2 & 16.1
OSX: 14.6.1

I don't know whether this is relevant, but what you're doing is not how to write an async stream. You need to put this whole thing into a class where both the stream and the continuation are properties. When you initialize the stream, its only action is to "unfold" the continuation into the property. Now other code can call the continuation's yield and this will cause the stream to emit a value to anyone awaiting it. — As for the question you actually asked, you're not providing enough info; a lot of the question is about an actor that doesn't even appear in your code.
